# How to implement sensor fusion with IMU and GPS

Tags: recommendations, sensor, imu, filters

I have a 9-axis `IMU` (`MPU9250`) and a `GPS` module and I'm considering using other sensors later, but I would like to correct the slip and measurement difference that may have between them, in order to obtain a single, more reliable data.

I saw indications of using `Kalman filter` to correct `IMU` slippage, and I saw issues related to sensor fusion.

Is there any method, library (preference in `C/C++`) or reference on how to implement or a better way to implement sensor fusion in this context?
I'm developing a data acquisition system to later control a drone.